# How to copy List items from two different List objects

Tags: java, object, generics, copy, listitem

I have two lists like below:

```
List<TemplateObject> list1;
List<InUseObject> list2;
```

I need to read from Template (source) and create new Instance of InUse (target) by getting all element values copied from Template. Given all the fields/elements have same data type in both the lists.

There are multiple ways of achieving it (say clone, shallow/deep copying).

Question: How do I achieve it using Java 8+. Preferably one liner may be?

Comment: Please provide the class definitions.

Comment: Do you want to combine the two `List`s into a third `List`?

Comment: No just need to copy Source elements to Target. One to one mapping of list elements.

Comment: How do you expect to convert from `TemplateObject` to `InUseObject`?

Comment: List<InUseObject> list2 = list1.stream().map(InUseObject::getInUseObjFromTemplateObj).collect(Collectors.toList()); might work. Put your mapping logic method "static InUseObject getInUseObjFromTemplateObj(TemplateObject)" method

Comment: Do you have constructors?

Comment: Yes I have constructors like this - public TemplateObject(Long id, String propertyname, String propertyvalue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Stream#map` like so:

```
List<InUseObject> list2 = list1.stream()
        .map(obj -> new InUseObject(obj.getId(), obj.getPropertyname(), obj.getPropertyvalue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also define a constructor in `InUseObject` accepting a `TemplateObject`:

```
public InUseObject(final TemplateObject obj) {
    this(obj.getId(), obj.getPropertyname(), obj.getPropertyvalue());
}
```

You can then use a constructor reference when mapping.

```
List<InUseObject> list2 = list1.stream()
        .map(InUseObject::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<InUseObject> out = in.stream()
                          .map(InUseObject::new)
                          .collect(Collectors::toList);
```

Of course your InUseObject has to copy every common field from TemplateObject in its constructor.

Comment: Looks neat. Will try it Frighi and will let you know. Thanks.